# Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init()

Tags: qt, ubuntu, opencv, gtk

Whenever I use OpenCV's `cv::imshow` alongside with Qt's `QApplication`, I get this error:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init()
```

I did some searching and ended up reading more and more about stuff I don't fully understand, but got some ideas how OpenCV and GTK+ are connected. And since the warning is obviously an instruction to call something before something, I included `gtk.h` and called `gtk_disable_setlocale()`, but ended up with even more errors.

My code runs despite the warning without any problem, but it really bugs me! And I assume that behind the warning, there are some essential stuff a programmer should understand. So maybe somebody can explain the whole thing in a way an advanced newbie can understand? ;)

**Edit:**
I'm using ubuntu 12.10, OpenCV 2.4, GTK 2.24.13 and `qmake -v` tells me

```
QMake version 2.01a 
Using Qt version 4.8.3 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Are you running on Linux? Which distro?

Comment: I can confirm that this conflict between opencv/qt/gtk is still present in Ubuntu 14.04. It seems to break imshow if some other part of your program is using qt.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use Qt windowing system, it's best to avoid creating OpenCV windows alongside with Qt windows.

**Convert `IplImage` or `cv::Mat` to `QImage`** and draw that on a Qt window. [Check cvImage](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/cvImage), a  simple Qt/OpenCV example that displays an image loaded with OpenCV on a Qt window, and also shows the RGB values of a pixel based on mouse coordinates.

Comment: I do convert the `cv::Mat`s to `QImage`s to display the final result. It's just that `cv::imshow()` comes in handy, when I need do look at some intermediate results. I just want to understand what the warning is about.

Comment: There's so much that `cv::imshow()` does behind your back that could cause that conflict. I guess the only way to really understand it is to debug the application and see where it takes you.